# Why does proguard ignores my rules?

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

I've got a `proguard-rules.txt` which clearly is ignored by my build in android studio.

I keep getting:

```
Warning: org.spongycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper: can't find referenced class javax.naming.directory.DirContext
```

and:

```
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.mycompany.myClass { long getMetadata(com.mycompany.Metadata,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.mycompany.Metadata'
```

Even though I have:

```
-dontwarn javax.naming.**
```

and

```
-keep,includedescriptorclasses public class com.mycompany.** {
    public protected *;
}
-keep,includedescriptorclasses public enum com.mycompany.** {
    public protected *;
}
-keep,includedescriptorclasses public interface com.mycompany.** {
    public protected *;
}
```

It's just an example, I have a lot of rules which are ignored and classes are removed even though I have a `-keep` rule for them. Also, the contents of the `build/intermediates/proguard-rules/release/aapt_rules.txt` suggest that my rules are ignored - none of them are there.

Here's my config:

**build.gradle**

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), "proguard-rules.txt"
        }
    }
```

**proguard-rules.txt** [part with a connection to the question]

```
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep,includedescriptorclasses public class com.mycompany.** {
    public protected *;
}
-keep,includedescriptorclasses public enum com.mycompany.** {
    public protected *;
}
-keep,includedescriptorclasses public interface com.mycompany.** {
    public protected *;
}
# SPONGYCASTLE
-keep class org.spongycastle.crypto.* {*;}
-keep class org.spongycastle.crypto.agreement.** {*;}
-keep class org.spongycastle.crypto.digests.* {*;}
-keep class org.spongycastle.crypto.ec.* {*;}
-keep class org.spongycastle.crypto.encodings.* {*;}
-keep class org.spongycastle.crypto.engines.* {*;}
-keep class org.spongycastle.crypto.macs.* {*;}
-keep class org.spongycastle.crypto.modes.* {*;}
-keep class org.spongycastle.crypto.paddings.* {*;}
-keep class org.spongycastle.crypto.params.* {*;}
-keep class org.spongycastle.crypto.prng.* {*;}
-keep class org.spongycastle.crypto.signers.* {*;}

-keep class org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.* {*;}
-keep class org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.util.* {*;}
-keep class org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.dh.* {*;}
-keep class org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.* {*;}

-keep class org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.digest.** {*;}
-keep class org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.** {*;}
-keep class org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.** {*;}
-keep class org.spongycastle.jcajce.spec.* {*;}
-keep class org.spongycastle.jce.** {*;}


-dontwarn javax.naming.**
```

Could someone tell me what's going on? It seems to be done 'by the book' but I can't figure this out.

**EDIT:**

I just wanted to add, that the:

```
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'com.mycompany.myClass { long getMetadata(com.mycompany.Metadata,long); }', but not the descriptor class 'com.mycompany.Metadata'
```

log, which would suggest that the rules are read because `com.mycomany.myClass` is kept, comes from the default android rules, which will keep classes specified in `AndroidManifest.xml` file. This is not because of my rules in my `proguard-rules.txt` file.

**EDIT2:**
I have modified my spongycastle config to:

```
# SPONGYCASTLE
-keep class org.spongycastle.** {*;}
-dontwarn org.spongycastle.**
-dontwarn javax.naming.**
```

but I still get the same warnings about spongycastle's classes which can't find referenced classes in `javax.naming`.